# How to type a dynamic file entry for org capture

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to figure out if there is some way to create a dynamic file name for capture in emacs org-mode.

```
("z" "test" entry (file+headline ***A date specific headline*** "Notes"))
    "** %^{prompt}")
```

Is there some simple way to pass a date and year to the file part, so that I can have a file dynamically created for each month.  What I'd like is something like this:

```
(concat "/home/me/file/report_notes_" (format-time-string "%m_%Y") ".org")
```

Edit - I've finally got it working, using backquoting:

```
`(("z" "test" entry (file+headline ,(capture-report-date-file "/path/path/name_")
   "Notes")
   "** %^{prompt}")))
```

then writing a function like this:

```
(defun capture-report-date-file (path)
  (concat path (format-time-string "%m_%Y")))
```

I got to the answer after reading  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809986/233057) to a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at "org-daypage": https://github.com/almost/org-daypage

Right now it creates a page for the current day and saves it to a specific directory, maybe you can modify the code according to your needs.