# Org-Mode - How do I create a new file with org-capture?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to create an org-capture template that create a dynamic file name for capture in emacs org-mode.

I want that the name of the file takes the following form:
(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d") "-" (prompt for a name) ".txt"

Example : 2012-08-10-MyNewFile.txt

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614642/how-to-type-a-dynamic-file-entry-for-org-capture) answer, I know how to dynamically create the name the file to include the date:

```lisp
`(defun capture-report-date-file (path)
(expand-file-name (concat path (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d") ".txt")))

'(("t" "todo" entry (file (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name"))
"* TODO")))
```

This allows me to create a file 2012-08-10.txt and to insert * TODO at the first line

How could I add a prompt to complete the file name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to use `(read-string ...)` in `capture-report-data-file` to generate the filename on the fly.

```lisp
(defun capture-report-date-file (path)
  (let ((name (read-string "Name: ")))
    (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.txt"
                              (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
                              name) path)))

'(("t"
   "todo"
   entry
   (file (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name"))
   "* TODO")))
```

This will prompt on capture for the file name, and then open the capture buffer will be created.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan. It's perfect.

Comment: This does not work for me. I just get an "invalid file" error?

Comment: This does not work for me either and looking for a solution. It returns "invalid file location: nil". Does this come after "(setq org-capture-templates"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use below template & function to create new file.

```
  (defun psachin/create-notes-file ()
    "Create an org file in ~/notes/."
    (interactive)
    (let ((name (read-string "Filename: ")))
      (expand-file-name (format "%s.org"
                                  name) "~/notes/")))



   (setq org-capture-templates
     '(("n" "Notes" entry
        (file psachin/create-notes-file)
       "* TITLE%?\n %U")))
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this work with capture templates only or just by calling the function directly=