# Creating a new text file in a diretory using org-capture

Tags: templates, org-mode

Following this response: [Org-Mode - How do I create a new file with org-capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902620/org-mode-how-do-i-create-a-new-file-with-org-capture?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I am trying to make this piece of code work, but I get the error: `invalid file location: nil`.

```
(defun capture-report-data-file (path)
  (let ((name (read-string "Name: ")))
    (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.txt"
                              (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
                              name) path)))

'(("t"
   "todo"
   entry
   (file (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name"))
   "* TODO")))
```

Comment: Instead of file you need to specify it as a function. I have examples on my config here -> https://github.com/nmartin84/.doom.d

Comment: Actually, it's a problem of coding in the new Emacs. Using (file (lambda () (capture-report-date-file "~path))) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it works like this:

Replace

```
(file (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name"))
```

with

```
(file (lambda () (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name")))
```