# Org Capture: prompt for information when determining the target file

Tags: emacs, org-mode, dot-emacs

I'm looking to build a capture template that, when run, prompts the user for more information to determine the path of the target file.

I have a few pieces already.

A function which asks the user for data and returns a string:

```lisp
(defun my/get-121-orgfile ()
  "Ask the user for the name of the participant so that we can build"
  (interactive)
  (read-string "Participant Name: ")
)
```

An `org-capture-template` which will run the prompt successfully when emacs loads:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
    `(
      ("m1" "1-1 meetings")
      ("m1b" "prep for a 1-1 meeting" entry
       (file ,(concat "~/org/meetings/1-2-1/" (my/get-121-orgfile) ".org"))
       (file "~/org/templates/meeting-121-prep.org")
       :clock-in t)
))
```

I took the back quote and comma pattern from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875921/315827), but I haven't been able to figure out how to scope this behaviour to when I select the template: I want the prompt to pop up each time I hit `<org-capture>m1b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backquote-comma pattern will not help here: it will call the function at the time that `org-capture-template` is set. What you are trying to do is to call the function when the capture is executed.

The only way I know to do that would to use the `(function foo)` target mechanism of `org-capture-templates`. The doc string says:

> ```
>         (function function-finding-location)
>             Most general way: write your own function which both visits
>             the file and moves point to the right location
> ```

So you would not be able to use the `(file ...)` target as you do above. Instead you have to write a function that gets all the information you want and then visit the target file at the target location and add the filled-out template.

This is not a complete answer but it was too long for a comment, but maybe it helps to point you in the right direction.